# pause slick slider autoplay when video/second slide

Tags: wordpress, slider

Iam using https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ slick slider and I want to use autoplay but it also autoplays video's. I tried pausing autoplay when theres a video but its to complicated for me so maybe its easier to pause the slider on the second slide (because the video is always on the second slide of the slider). But I can't find a solution to this.

edit: youtube embed is already autoplaying

iframe looks like this

```
                        <iframe class="embed-player slide-media "
                            src="<?php echo esc_url($url); ?>?controls=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&loop=1&mute=1&playlist=<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>&start=1"
                            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Check the below link for your reference.
```

[Reference Link for Pausing Slick Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301432/slick-carousel-pause-the-slick-autoplay-when-youtube-video-is-playing)